# EntityType has no key defined. [Key] is presented

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Entity

```
public class Region
{
    [Key]
    public int ID;
    public string Name; 
    public string Description;
}
```

Model

```
public class RegionModel
{   [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Errors

> System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Region' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �Regions� is based
>   on type �Region� that has no keys defined.

Answer (score 6):

Your class fields need to be changed to properties for EF to use the class correctly;

```
public class Region
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Region
{
    [Key]
    public int RegionId{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;} 
    public string Description{get;set;}
}

public class RegionModel
{   [Key]
    public int RegionModelId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

It works if you have it like `ClassNameId`.You can even remove `[Key]` attribute now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a strange answer to your problem. But be sure that your project compiles first. i got the same errors when i had added the dataanotations without compiling the project.

I think the code is generated with some kind of reflection.